# Symfony: 'zlib extension' missing

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu-12.04, php-5.5

I wanted to start with Symfony, but I even fail a the Quick Tour...

```
$ php -r "readfile('http://symfony.com/installer');" > symfony.phar
$ sudo mv symfony.phar /usr/local/bin/symfony
$ chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/symfony

$ symfony 
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PharException' with message 'zlib extension is required for gz compressed .phar file "/usr/local/bin/symfony"' in /usr/local/bin/symfony:9
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/local/bin/symfony(9): Phar::mapPhar('default.phar')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /usr/local/bin/symfony on line 9

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PharException' with message 'zlib extension is required for gz compressed .phar file "/usr/local/bin/symfony"' in /usr/local/bin/symfony:9
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/local/bin/symfony(9): Phar::mapPhar('default.phar')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /usr/local/bin/symfony on line 9
```

I have only rudimentary knowledge of apt-get and no idea how to install php extensions.

How can I solve this problem?

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

```
php --version
PHP 5.5.3 (cli) (built: Sep  1 2013 14:29:12)
```

Thanks.

Comment: I can't even remember installing php5.5, but I 'solved' it with a vm with 14.04...

Answer (score 2):

I think PHP supports Zlib but it is not enable by default [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/zlib.installation.php)

You can add the option --with-zlib --with-zlib=DIR when you configure your php to enable the zlib.

Example:

php_5.6.7$ ./configure --with-zlib --with-zlib=DIR

Thank,